# Code igniter and wamp not finding files in different folder

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, wamp, codeigniter-routing

I happened to run into this problem with a code igniter based folder/site in my wamp's www folder, the folder is named igniter and the site works great on that folder, but when I copy paste that folder or simply rename it, the routing stops working.

To be more specific, I enter the newly renamed folder/site via browser, like `http://localhost/igniter2` for example, and the code igniter routes to the default/homepage intended but when I try to access any other page via links or direct routing all I get is a 404 page not found error, even if I try to click the homepage link in the homepage it gets the same error.

I tried to look everyone but didn't find answer, can someone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: have you checked .htaccess?

Comment: thanks, i was able to see the problem there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the file www/igniter2/.htaccess and on the first 3 lines i saw:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteBase /igniter/
```

and changed to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /igniter2/
```

Now works wonders :) thanks curious_coder for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

Change the 'base_url' parameter to '`http://localhost/<new_folder_name>/`' in config.php.

config.php is present in 'application/config/' folder.

In your case:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/igniter2/';
```